# Trying to display two sf datasets in r via ggplot but not getting the expected result

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geospatial, r-sf

**Hi,

Trying to overlay one shp map (Mexico city) with the dataset from kaggle for airbnb (in Mexico city) in r. If I plot them separately it work fine, but when trying to plot them together it shows something weird... here is the code and results so far:**

```
cdmx3 <- st_read("inegi/09_CDMX/cartografia/municipal.shp")
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = cdmx3, color = "black") + 
  ggtitle("Municipios de CDMX")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tR5b.png)

```
airbnb_mexico <- read.csv(file = "listings.csv")
airbnb_mexico_sf <- st_as_sf(x = airbnb_mexico, coords = c("longitude","latitude"))
ggplot() + 
  ggtitle("Municipios de CDMX") + 
  geom_sf(data= airbnb_mexico_sf, color = "blue")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6X5e.png)

```
st_crs(airbnb_mexico_sf) <- st_crs(cdmx3)
```

**But when trying to overlay, it shows this:**

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = cdmx3, color = "black", fill = "cyan1") + 
  ggtitle("Municipios de CDMX") + 
  geom_sf(data= airbnb_mexico_sf, color = "blue")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55MdY.png)

**Here is a summary of each sf file:**

> cdmx3
> Simple feature collection with 16 features and 261 fields
> Geometry type: POLYGON
> Dimension:     XY
> Bounding box:  xmin: 2776218 ymin: 786788.9 xmax: 2820850 ymax: 846749.5
> Projected CRS: Mexico_ITRF2008_LCC
> First 10 features:...

> airbnb_mexico_sf
> Simple feature collection with 19852 features and 14 fields
> Geometry type: POINT
> Dimension:     XY
> Bounding box:  xmin: -99.33963 ymin: 19.16914 xmax: -98.96297 ymax: 19.55734
> Projected CRS: Mexico_ITRF2008_LCC
> First 10 features:...

**Any feedback or suggestion is greatly appreciated... **

I tried having both sf sets to have the same CRS (Mexico_ITRF2008_LCC) but it did nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change this line:

```r
    st_crs(airbnb_mexico_sf) <- st_crs(cdmx3)
```

to

```r
    airbnb_mexico_sf <- airbnb_mexico_sf %>%
       st_transform(crs = st_crs(cdmx3))
```

The issue is that you are overwriting CRS information without actually reprojecting the shape. Which is what you need to do...

The direct assigment of st_crs() is best reserved for error corrections - situations when information about CRS is present, but known to be wrong.

Also consider replacing

```r
airbnb_mexico_sf <- st_as_sf(x = airbnb_mexico, coords = c("longitude","latitude"))
```

with

```r
airbnb_mexico_sf <- st_as_sf(x = airbnb_mexico, coords = c("longitude","latitude"), crs = 4326)
```

The crs = 4326 is important, it tells {sf} how to interpret your coordinates - do the numbers mean degrees of lat & long, or meters of distance? US Survey feet perhaps? The 4326 makes sure the data is interpreted in degrees on a sphere (a good default when dealing with GPS coordinates).

Comment: I tried the command and but the result is the same :(

Comment: that is strange, for the two function calls do two very different things... I am editing the answer for another possible culprit, but it is hard to make 100% sure without access to your data...

Comment: The last statement with CRS = 4326 WORKED FINE!!! THANKS!!!!!

Comment: You are the best Jindra Lacko!

Comment: I am glad it worked! And a fun fact: in Czech (my language) Enrique translates as Jindra. Not too common a name :) Enriques of the world, unite!

Comment: nice to know, now my new login account will be Jindra for other services! hahaha tks!